How fast is dd for image writes?
How fast does dd write on i.e. an SD card or a USB stick?
When I use the dd command to write i.e. a 4 GB Ubuntu image to an SD card or a USB stick, it just takes about 3 seconds until it is done:
myuser@mysystem:~/Downloads/UbuntuImage$ sudo dd if=ubuntu-core-22-armhf+raspi.img of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
875+0 records in
875+0 records out
3670016000 bytes (3.7 GB, 3.4 GiB) copied, 3.09567 s, 1.2 GB/s
myuser@mysystem:~/Downloads/UbuntuImage$

The thing with this example is, that I know exactly, that my SD card can only write about 30 MB/s. Therefore, it is impossible to write the image in a speed as indicated with 1.2 GB/s within 3 seconds. It should take much longer than that, like about 100 seconds. I guess that the command itself is done that quick, but in the background there has to be some kind of application finishing the job in the real speed.
How can I get the real speed of the image write? How can I check if the writing process on the SD card is accomplished?

Data is buffered on writing, thus the command that writes the date can commonly return before the actual writing has completed; it's why sync and like commands allow us to ensure data write has completed.

@guiverc that should be enough for an answer ;)  20% of available memory is used for that buffer. echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio to reduce it to 1% Oh and a VERY bad idea to keep on 1%... use it to test the SD but do keep it on 20 for normal usage

I have almost no detail on get the real speed of the image write; outside of setting up a timer on a write & calculating on that... and I have no interest in that @Rinzwind  ..   besides it's after midnight local time & bed is more appealing...

@guiverc I got you covered  ;-)

Ok, sync seems to do the trick. Even though IMHO, I guess a preferable way would be to get a choice of waiting / not waiting using a dd parameter.
